# Do features uninstall variables when a module is uninstalled?

Tags: 7, features

I have created a module using The Features module. The module exports some variables using the Strongarm module.

If a person installs the module and then uninstalls it, will those variables be removed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it does not. Features do not implement an uninstall hook, and as such don't get a chance to clean up after themselves.